# try to restrict ips via regular expression

Tags: regex, limit

Trying to restrict the following ip range from tracking:

example:

123.142.132.217-222

Now the what i was originally thinking was:

^46.140.137.[217 - 222]

However this will just mach any number in that range. What is the cleanest way to catch this ending number group?

Thanks

City

Comment: Not with a regex; use an IP and a subnet mask, though it's slightly wrong, here, since you can only mask by powers of 2. ```123.142.132.216/29```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty specific question, but the answer, I suppose, is worthwhile.

The number range 217-222 is captured with

```
2(?:1[7-9]|2[0-2])
```

In your IP example, don't forget to escape the dots

```
123\.142\.132\.2(?:1[7-9]|2[0-2])
```

Comment: awww passive group... Thanks man was struggling with how to group those number ranges.